# Fujtisu Eternus DX80 change iSCSI Discovery Reply Mode

Tags: storage-area-network, iscsi, xenserver, multipath

I have a configuration mistake in my dx80 and the system is already in production. I have to set "iSCSI Discovery Reply Mode" at "Host Response" configuration to "All - Reply All Ports (Default)". Is it safe to change this value in operation, or do I really need a downtime? Some practice experience would be great.

There are 11 XenServer attached to it with multipathing. 4 of 4 paths active but just 1 iSCSI session (thats the reason why I need to change this setting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no harm in changing the "Host Response" setting for the iSCSI Discovery parameter.  All it does is change the response to the next SendTargets command from the iSCSI Initiators. You do need to be careful that it's the only parameter that is being changed.